# PowerShell - Get-ACL not returning all permissions

Tags: powershell, acl

I tried to read out permissions from various folders with the `Get-ACL` cmdlet.
It works well and I can see the authorized users with `Get-ACL $path | %{$_.Access}`. But I noticed that some permissions are missing.
If I go into any folders `properties > Security (Tab) > Advanced` I am able to see the respective permissions and to what they apply to.
Some permissions are set to apply to `nothing` and those are not shown by `Get-ACL`.

This leads me to my question:
Is there any way to read out the `Applies to` field of an acl?
I tried using the .NET function `[System.IO.Directory]::GetAccessControl()` but it didn't provide this information.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

To clarify the issue I took some screenshots:

This shows the permission that is set to apply to "nothing".
It seems as if this is an error, since I am not able to select "nothing" for any other permission entry.

[image: Permission that applies to nothing]

And this is the acl as returned via Powershell ("OWNER RIGHTS" is missing):

[image: The "nothing" permission does not show]

Answer (score 0):

Applies to "nothing" is not a valid value AFAIK, so here we need proof.

The Applies to field is a combination of `InheritanceFlags` and `PropagationFlags`, and the value "None" in both of those equals Applies to this folder only. Those will show with `Get-ACL`.

```
PS C:\Users\frode> (Get-Acl .\Desktop\test).Access

#Applies to: Subfolder and files only
FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : frode-pc\frode
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

#Applies to: This folder only
FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : frode-pc\frodetest
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
```

Comment: I added some screenshots to show the issue. "nothing" seems to be an invalid value indedd, but it got set somehow (as you can see in the screenshot). This is a really strange situation...

Comment: Owner rights are special. You've probably changed owner on the resource which will set owner rights permissions to Nothing (which disables the rule). At least according to this http://m.windowsitpro.com/article/security/acl-enhancements-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-102871  . I don't know how to show those. :-/

Comment: Maybe there is no way to show those entries... Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: The GUI finds it, so it's definitely possible, but you may have to use pinvoke to  get there. :-)